# Is there a way to set the database(test, prod) when performing a goose migration?

Tags: go, goose

I'm trying to create 3 different inserts for each stand, but didn't found the correct way to do it.
For example, in liquidbase it was possible to specify the desired context and then migrations were applied only in the right places.
I want to see something like:
-- +goose context:test, dev